# Why wasn't fast-vector-highlighter (lucene-contrib) made an official part of Lucene 3.0 core

Tags: lucene, highlighting

I've read some Jira entries and they mentioned moving fast-vector-highlighter to core about a year ago but it never made it.

Looking at the [svn](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/lucene/contrib/highlighter/src) for contrib it seems incomplete.

- There are no tests for FastVectorHighlighter
- Documentation is lacking
- No samples anywhere on apache.org

Anyone have any ideas what its status is?

Comment: Good question. However, I wonder if you get it answered here. Maybe the lucene-dev mailing list is a better place to ask this.

Answer (score 0):

It is [in core on the 3.x branch](https://hudson.apache.org/hudson/job/Lucene-3.x/javadoc/all/org/apache/lucene/search/vectorhighlight/FastVectorHighlighter.html), available in [stable builds](https://hudson.apache.org/hudson/job/Lucene-3.x/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/) and will be in the 3.1 release.